# Which is the best mudra for meditation (likely to help in concentration)?

Tags: meditation, spiritual-level

I have seen many type of mudras as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mudras_%28yoga%29) but I am unable to conclude which is best one, for developing concentration.Which in turn will give better results in meditation.

Following are the pictures of mudras which I found are important in meditation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it depends on the kind of meditation and the kind of position that suits you

Comment: In the beginning do the one that feels most natural to you, that you can do with ease, but the right hand should always be held in the left (as can be seen in both pics). Beyond that, you should find a teacher and ask him. Specific mudras become more important after you learn to control the flow of prana in the body.

Comment: Swamiji Pranam, sir I agree with you but there should be a generalization for mudras, or should I make a trial and error test? The one which sends me to highest level of consciousness? I would like to know what scriptures have in them , what is their opinion in this topic scriptures like gherand samhita or patanjali yoga sutras

Comment: A mudra in and by itself will not send you to a higher level of consciousness. Meditation and concentration will do that. Most people learn from their teacher. Learn meditation and through that learn to control the prana. When you know how to control the prana, your body and mind will tell you which mudra(s) are best for you.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Going through mudra topics on here and found this thread from seven years ago, thx for the comments you had posted here, so helpful ! :) Also wanted to say, the comments you and Milind posted on various threads re Hinduism time cycles were very informative too, helped me understand so much, thx for that too :)

Answer (score 3):

1. GYAN MUDRA – FOR WISDOM
2. VAAYU MUDRA – FOR CALMNESS
3. AAKASH MUDRA – FOR LIGHTNESS
4. SHUNYA MUDRA – FOR PAIN RELIEF
5. PRITHVI MUDRA – FOR STRENGTH
6. SURYA MUDRA – FOR WEIGHT LOSS
7. VARUN MUDRA – FOR MOISTURIZATION
8. JAL SHAAMAK MUDRA – FOR STABILITY

Thease are the very usefull mudras
For the detail description please refer [this link](http://workouttrends.com/mudras-hand-gestures-yoga-and-meditation).

For the meditation,
These both mudras are best you can't define best one out of both,it depends on person who gets it very useful, some can meditate with first mudra and other with second one.

If you want to know more about it here is [another link](https://yogainternational.com/article/view/2-meditation-mudras) .

Comment: Your answer is good but the reference is not a scripture related to hindusism, also your answer is incomplete because you haven't specified the best out of these/ or shastra opinion for best of these mudras for medetation

Comment: These are the best mudras for different purpose ,as you can see I have also described the mudra with the purpose.any way I will try to improve the answer if you find this answer helpfull please upvote it.

Comment: As @Creator said, it would be better if you could cite scripture.